# Pentaho insert a list in sql where clause

Tags: pentaho, where-clause

I am new to Pentaho and I am running a transformation where by I am first querying a database to get a list of ids and then I am to use the list in the where clause of a sql statement that queries another data base. i.e.

where order_id in ({list})

How do specify variables (the list of ids) and then add them to the query statement in table input in penthao?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can cause a variable to be expanded in a `Table input` step by checking "Replace variables in script?" and specifying `where order_id in(${list})`.

However if the list of values is long, I would consider using a `Stream Lookup` step instead. The Stream lookup step reads values from one source into a cache at the start of the transformation run and then does a lookup into the cache for each row that flows through it during the regular run.

It would look something like this:

[image]

The values from "Data Grid" will be read first, then used as a lookup cache for all values from the "Table input" step. You can then add a `Filter rows` step to flow off anything that fails the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to do this but they're not very effective. Unless your query is very very large I think you're better off running it *without* the 'where order_id in {list}'  filter and using a stream lookup step to get the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Dynamic SQL join:**

You may use a combination of Table input -> Group By -> Modified Java Script Value -> Dynamic SQL join.

**Table input** will select list of IDs as required.

In **Group By** you can aggregate list of IDs into one comma-separated String (

```
Name: "list" (the name of output field with list of IDs)
Subject: name of the field with IDs from your Table Input,
Type: "Concatenate strings separated by ,"
```

)

In **Modified Java Script Value** you may define an XML literal, containing your SQL query (you may use a String instead and replace {list} with the value if you don't mind keeping your query in one line).

```
var sqlQuery = <>
    SELECT
        *
    FROM table_name
    WHERE
        order_id IN ( {list} )
</>
```

If you use it like this, then `{list}` will be automatically substituted with value of `list` variable (or column value). But you'll need to escape < and > characters inside your query.
Alternatively, you may put your query in CDATA:

```
var sqlQuery = <>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT
            *
        FROM table_name
        WHERE
            order_id IN ( {list} )    
    ]]>
</>
```

you will not need to escape <> characters, but you'll need to substitute `list` yourself afterwards: `sqlQuery = sqlQuery.toString().replace("{list}", list, "g")`

And finally you have to specify your sqlQuery variable in "Fields" table of JS step, so that it will be added as a new field to each row.

Then in **Dynamic SQL join** you need to specify sqlQuery field in `SQL field name`. In `Template SQL` you have to put any query, that has same data types as your generated query, e.g. something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1=0
```